# Intersection of two hypersurfaces via... Bezout's theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M_1,M_2 \subset \mathbf{S}^n$ be two smoothly embedded, connected hypersurfaces of the round sphere, which are realized as the zero sets of two homogeneous polynomials $P_1,P_2$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$:
\begin{equation}
M_i = \{ P_i = 0 \} \cap \mathbf{S}^n.
\end{equation}

> Is there an upper bound for the number of connected components of $M_1 \setminus M_2$ in terms of $\operatorname{deg} P_1$ and $\operatorname{deg} P_2$?

I apologize for the elementary question; my impression is that it might follow from Bezout's theorem, perhaps combined with Mayer–Vietoris, but I'm not an algebraic geometer by trade, so I can't say for certain. (I'd be happy to look up references myself if you have a suggestion!)

Comment: Are you looking for real intersection points or complex ones?

Comment: Real - I guess it's basically a differential geometry question, just that the hypersurfaces considered happen to be algebraic. (Is what I said about $M_1 \cap M_2 \neq \emptyset$ false in this case, because the field isn't algebraically closed?)

Comment: Think about two very thin quadratic cones, so their zeroes intersect the sphere in tiny circles, which don't have to intersect; they can be any circles, appearing in antipodally symmetric pairs.

Comment: OK, you're right - I'll update the question. I'm honestly mostly interested in an upper bound for the number connected components, so perhaps this is still OK as a question?

Comment: Such upper bounds exist, just by "quasi-compactness."  I guess you are looking for an effective upper bound.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Proposition 4.13 of Coste’s introduction to semi-algebraic geometry, a bound of $d(2d-1)^{s+k-1}$ is given for the number of connected components of a system of $s$ real polynomial equations and inequations of degree at most $d\ge 2$ in $k$ variables. In your case, $k=n+1$ and $s=3$.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Yowza, those bounds are brutal! I'll leave the question open for now, perhaps someone sees a shortcut that uses the fact that $M_i = P_i^{-1}(0) \cap \mathbf{S}^n$ are both connected. I hope you won't take offence! (In the meantime, I'll check if the library has a copy of the book; thanks for the suggestion.)

Comment: OK, it looks like nobody's biting - thanks again for your answer! I'm still a bit taken aback that the bounds would so bad; my expectation was a bound by $\operatorname{deg} P_1 \operatorname{deg} P_2$, but perhaps I was a bit naive...